# popstate HTML 5 event being fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Hi i am using the following code to load a part of page dynamically using jquery

```
loadNextBackInPage_URL = null;
function callBackFunctionLoadNextBackInPage(data)
{
    //alert(data);
    $("#left").fadeTo(100,1);
    var data = $(data).find( '#left' );
    $("#left").html(data);
    if(supports_history_api())
    {
        history.pushState(null, null, loadNextBackInPage_URL);
        window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
        alert('s');
        loadNextBackInPage(location.pathname);
        });
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
function loadNextBackInPage(url,parm)
{
    //alert(url);
    loadNextBackInPage_URL = url;
    $("#left").fadeTo(100,.2);
    $.post(url,parm,callBackFunctionLoadNextBackInPage,'html');


}
```

The loading part and even changing the browser URL is working. but why is the PoP state function being fired multiple times?

I call loadNextBackInPage() originally through an onclick function.

Comment: any one could you help whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it solved from here in [codingforums](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=228029)

> think you keep adding "popstate"
>   listeners over and over ...
>
> Program logic:

1. Page loaded
2. onclick will execute loadNextBackInPage()
3. Start a $.post() Request and fire "callBackFunctionLoadNextBackInPage" on completion
4. pushState()
5. Register an event listener for "popstate"
6. When "popstate" fires, execute loadNextBackInPage() and return to step 2

> So step 4 will be executed over and
>   over which will register new event
>   listeners. Every time "popstate" fires
>   all the event listeners will execute
>
> Try to move the addEventListener
>   method call out of this loop

So from those i derived a workaround and also corrected `location.pathname` to `location.href`

The corrected code:

```
loadNextBackInPage_URL = null;
popEventListnerAdded = false;


function callBackFunctionLoadNextBackInPage(data)
{
    //alert(data);
    $("#left").fadeTo(100,1);
    var data = $(data).find( '#left' );
    $("#left").html(data);
    if(supports_history_api())
    {
        history.pushState(null, null, loadNextBackInPage_URL);  
        if(!popEventListnerAdded) {
            window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
            loadNextBackInPage(location.href);
            });
            popEventListnerAdded = true;
        }

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
function loadNextBackInPage(url,parm)
{
    //alert(url);
    loadNextBackInPage_URL = url;
    $("#left").fadeTo(100,.2);
    $.post(url,parm,callBackFunctionLoadNextBackInPage,'html');
}
```